# Swiftmailer Failed to encrypt S/Mime message. Error: "error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line"

Tags: encryption, swiftmailer

I'm trying to encrypt a message in SwiftMailer.

The relevant code looks like this:

```
$smimeSigner = Swift_Signers_SMimeSigner::newInstance();
$smimeSigner->setEncryptCertificate('cert.pem', OPENSSL_CIPHER_AES_256_CBC);
$message->attachSigner($smimeSigner);
```

AES256 is required for this project

The certificate file was converted by openssl from a .cer to a .pem with no complaints and appeared to work.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<snip>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I get the following error:

```
Swift_IoException: Failed to encrypt S/Mime message. Error: "error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line". in ~project/common-incl/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Signers/SMimeSigner.php:318
  Stack trace:
  #0 ~project/common-incl/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Signers/SMimeSigner.php(260): Swift_Signers_SMimeSigner->messageStreamToEncryptedByteStream(Object(Swift_ByteStream_TemporaryFileByteStream), Object(Swift_ByteStream_TemporaryFileByteStream))
  #1 ~project/common-incl/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Signers/SMimeSigner.php(218): Swift_Signers_SMimeSigner->toSMimeByteStream(Object(Swift_ByteStream_TemporaryFileByteStream), Object(Swift_Message))
  #2 ~project/common-incl/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Message.php(199): Swift_Signers_SMimeSigner->signMessage(Object(Swift_Message))
  #3 ~project/common-incl/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Message.php(179): Swift_Message->doSign()
  #4 ~project/common-incl/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(327): Swift_Message->toByteStream(Object(Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer))
  #5 ~project/common-incl/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(428): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_streamMessage(Object(Swift_Message))
  #6 ~project/common-incl/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(444): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_doMailTransaction(Object(Swift_Message), '****@comca...', Array, Array)
  #7 ~project/common-incl/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(176): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_sendTo(Object(Swift_Message), '****@comca...', Array, Array)
  #8 ~project/common-incl/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mailer.php(85): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->send(Object(Swift_Message), Array)
  #9 ~project/m/dl/local-incl/mailFile.php(625): Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message))
  #10 ~project/m/d/ajax/saveData.php(1163): mailFile('RDON', '2018-01-10', 'email', Array, 'testingthings')
  #11 {main}
```

It's not clear to me why this error occurs. The .pem file appears to be in the correct format. The code after this uses an SMTP transport to send the message, and the message is correctly sent when not encrypting the message.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out SwiftMailer requires an absolute path. Rather than complaining that the certificate didn't exist, it returns this error.

So changing it to

`$smimeSigner->setEncryptCertificate(__DIR__.'/cert.pem');`

works.